# Need to query based on a query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to query from two tables in my database, where the foreign key/primary key is ID.

I need to pull out all my appts on the certain wk in my Appointments db, and then I need their first and last name from the Clients db. Right now, I am pulling out all the data from the Appointment database just fine, but I am unable to get my query for all the ids associated with each appt in the week to pull their information from my client db.

```
@app.route('/calendar/<wk>')
def calendar(wk):
    currentweek = Appointments.query.filter_by(week=wk).all()
    clientlist = Appointments.query(Appointments.clientID).filter_by(weekyr=wk).all()
    clients = Clients.query.filter(Clients.ID.in_(clientlist)).all()
    return render_template("calendarbyweek.html",currentweek=currentweek,clients=clients )
```

Comment: what is your error message/trace? or if no error what does clients return?

Comment: TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable   clientlist = Appointments.query(Appointments.clientID).filter_by(weekyr=wk).all()

Comment: That suggests the error is with clientlist, and perhaps you cannot have the '.all()' at the end. Is a clientlist returned correctly? Try using debug or inserting print(clientlist) after it is generated. You can see similar examples that don't use the 'all()' here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying At least if you try that you might get a different error which helps narrow it down.